# Select same column name in microsoft sql server from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

Is it possible to write a query:

```
SELECT * from table1, table 2, table 3 ...
```

where `table1.column` name like `table2.column` name like `table3.column` name

We don't know the name of our column, we say any of our columns which are in table1.**column name like** table2.**column name**  in like  table3.column name

For example: `employee id` maybe is a column that is common to 3 tables, or `publisher id` is a column that is common to 3 tables.

I can find the foreign key or primary key with a diagram in my database, but I want to write a query that shows just columns which have a same title as column name.

Answer (score 1):

No clue as to why you are doing this, so a bit hard to steer, but there are a number of tables  and views in the database that describe the database.

Information_Schema.Columns is probably where you should start. Note this is meta data, if you want the content of the actual tables you'll have to go a step further, and build some dynamic sql, or equivalent.

`Select Column_Name,Count(*) As NumberOfOccurences From Information_Schema.Columns` 
will give you the column names and how often you've used them for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the column name and want to know in which different table same column name is used then write SQL query as

SELECT schema_name(t.[schema_id]) + '.' + t.[name] AS Tables FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.[object_id] = c.[object_id] WHERE c.[name] = 'Your_Common_Column_Name'

You will get all the table list with their respective schema

Answer (score 0):

To get column names:

```
select sc.name
from sysobjects so inner join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id
where so.name = 'tableName'
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, it's better to use the new views in the `sys` schema, e.g. `sys.columns` and `sys.tables`

Comment: thank you HMariD,your syntax show all column name in one table,but my question is  just show the same column name in 3 table with their data. something like that union.

Comment: user1940864. You have to construct the sql to do something like that e.g. Exec('Select * From ' + @TableName) where you've got TableName from some query on the schema.