# How to select column names from multiple tables in SQL Server 2000-2008 that are in a set of names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

If I have a set of names like this:

```
('first', 'fname', 'firstname', 'namef', 'namefirst', 'name')
```

What is the best method in SQL Server 2000 - 2008 to retrieve the distinct table names that contain column names in the above set for a specific database?

And I wanted to exclude system table and temp tables from the list of tables that are displayed.

```
SELECT so.name
FROM   sysobjects so
       INNER JOIN syscolumns sc
            ON  so.id = sc.id
WHERE  sc.name IN ('first', 'fname', 'firstname', 'namef', 'namefirst', 'name')
```

This is a derivative of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113487/select-same-column-name-in-microsft-sql-server-from-multiple-tables) I believe.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For SQL Server 2005 and above

FWIW for newer versions of SQL Server I prefer the catalog views over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for the reasons outlined in this blog post:

[The case against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Also see warnings like this one on the topic [TABLES (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx) on MSDN:

> Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of an object is to query the sys.objects catalog view. INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features.

So the query I would use would be as follows (filtering out system objects and also avoiding #temp tables in the event you're in tempdb):

```
SELECT t.name, c.name
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE c.name IN (N'name', N'firstname', etc.)
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.name NOT LIKE '#%';
```

To repeat this for all databases:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
  UNION ALL SELECT db = N''' + name + ''', 
    t.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, 
    c.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + 'sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE c.name IN (N''name'', N''firstname'', etc.)
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.name NOT LIKE ''#%'''
FROM sys.databases
-- WHERE ... -- probably don't need system databases at least

SELECT @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 18, '') 
  -- you may have to adjust  ^^ 18 based on copy/paste, cr/lf, tabs etc.
  + ' ORDER BY by db, s.name, o.name';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(The `COLLATE` clauses are there to prevent errors in the case where you have databases with different collations.)

## For SQL Server 2000

Note that the above doesn't help for SQL Server 2000, but I don't think you should make it a goal to be able to run the same query on every single version. SQL Server 2000 is 13 years old and several years out of support; surely you can justify having special code for it. In which case I would still choose the query you have over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, just filter out system objects and temp tables (again, only relevant in the event you're in tempdb):

```
SELECT [object] = so.name, [column] = sc.name, 
  [type]  = st.name,   [precision] = st.xprec, 
  [scale] = st.xscale, st.length
FROM sysobjects AS so
INNER JOIN syscolumns AS sc
ON  so.id = sc.id
INNER JOIN systypes AS st
ON sc.xtype = st.xtype
WHERE sc.name IN 
  (N'first', N'fname', N'firstname', N'namef', N'namefirst', N'name')
AND so.name NOT LIKE '#%'
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(so.id, 'IsMsShipped') = 0;
```

You can do this for each database in SQL Server 2000 too, but since you can't use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` you will either have to use a cursor, a bunch of variables, or the [highly not-recommended sp_msforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/01/31/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb).

Comment: Can you please update the SQL Server 2000 query to display the datatype of the column also?

Comment: @Lijo ok, you'll have to work out length / 2 for nvarchar, putting precision / scale together for numeric types, etc. I also didn't cater to user-defined types...

Comment: Thanks... The query works perfectly.. Are you using some kind of a SQL fiddle? How did you come up with correct syntax on such an old database server?  [I understand that you are a master in SQL Server. Still wondering any fiddle to test this.]

Comment: @Lijo I have a virtual machine with 2000 RTM & SP4, 2005 RTM & SP4, 2008 RTM & SP3, 2008 R2 RTM & SP2, 2012 RTM & SP1, and several flavors of 2014 betas. Repro'ing something on a particular build is about as simple as starting a service.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TABLE_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
  WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME IN (your list of names)
```

I don't recall whether this includes temp tables, but you can look at the other columns in `TABLES` to see what to filter on.

Comment: How do I determine if a column name exists only for a specific database?

Comment: This script will only return results for the database that the connection is for.  You can prefix `INFOR...` with `DBNAME.`