# Database Tables with possible Join Candidates

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-modeling

Let's say I have some db tables created in SQL Server, those could be named Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 and Table5 (but could be more).

Now, what I want to achieve is to possibly mark the columns in those tables that could possibly indicate a candidate I could use for joining the tables.

Is this possible somehow with SQL? Or is there any SW Tool which could create a database model upon the data/tables which would join the tables with same column names?

Example could be with Business Intelligence table structures: I could have 5 tables and wanted to decide which dimension is shared for fact tables etc.

Comment: Those marks are called foreign keys.

Comment: Let's assume there exists no relationship of this kind.

Comment: @DNac i believe what you are referring to is candidate keys, now there is multiple ways to find what you are looking for but what it really comes down to is what defines each row as a unique row.
You can use SSIS for this, or you can refer to this script <github.com/jorriss/sp_dataprofile> to help you out. 
Also take into account that you might not be able to join on only one column and that you might be required to join on multiple ones to make a unique row.

Comment: How to identify fact tables:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/enterprise-solutions/identifying-fact-tables-data-warehouse-20810

Answer (score 0):

You could view all the columns with a certain piece of text in it, such as "%ID"
Use this script:

```
SELECT t.name As TableName, c.name AS ColumnName
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
  WHERE c.name Like ('%ID') --You can change ID to anything you need
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.name NOT LIKE '#%';
```

A similar question was posted here: [How to select column names from multiple tables in SQL Server 2000-2008 that are in a set of names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525279/how-to-select-column-names-from-multiple-tables-in-sql-server-2000-2008-that-are)